# GWT drag&drop how to get widget source on drop event

Tags: gwt, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to implement an drag & drop in my project.
I already managed, but now i want to distinguish the drag source.

I will have two widget from were i can drag lets call `widget1` and `widget2`:

```
widget1.getElement().setDraggable(Element.DRAGGABLE_TRUE);
widget2.getElement().setDraggable(Element.DRAGGABLE_TRUE);
```

i made the handler for each one

```
widget1.addDragStartHandler(new DragStartHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onDragStart(DragStartEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            event.setData("text", "i am widget1");
            });

widget2.addDragStartHandler(new DragStartHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onDragStart(DragStartEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            event.setData("text", "the text is different i am widget2");
```

now i had two absolute panels one only can receive from widget 1 and the other from widget 2

```
pNorth.addDomHandler(new DropHandler() {            
      @Override
       public void onDrop(DropEvent event) {
         if(widget1){
           // Prevent the native text drop.
            event.preventDefault();
             // Get the data out of the event.
              String text= event.getData("text");                                  
             pNorth.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundImage("url("+text+")");
           }}
         }, DropEvent.getType());
```

how can i manage to do that?

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The drop event doesn't seem to carry information about the source element.

So you have to use `event.setData("source", "some info about current widget");` to distinguish which element has been dragged. The info can be arbitrary, can be `widget1.getClass().getName()` or anything else allowing to distinguish what kind of widget has been dragged.

Note: the `"source"` tag is arbitrary, of course, you can use anything that suits you.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently worked on something called GWT DND (Drag & Drop). Its quite useful in these cases. Here is the **link**

http://code.google.com/p/gwt-dnd/

**Demo**

http://allen-sauer.com/com.allen_sauer.gwt.dnd.demo.DragDropDemo/DragDropDemo.html

Comment: thanks but that is to drag the widget imself and change is position i want to drag the info of the widget and then use is information.

Comment: Actually, you can use the same for your purpose also. The DND API can be used to drag elements inside the absolute panel you were mentioning.

Comment: Also, you can use JSNI methods over HTML5 Drag and Drop.

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_draganddrop.asp

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html

Comment: but the problem maintains is not possible to prevent other widgets like text areas or other widgets with drop handler to receive the drag.
Maybe i don't explain well my problem.

This suggestions you make seems to be alternatives to what i make.